# Run Windows Phone App in background without UI

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows phone 8 app that need to run only in background with UI. Is there any way I can run the app in the background, or without actually being open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon what you want to do in the background. Generally speaking you can't implement something like a Windows service that will startup automatically when the phone is launched.
That said you can run your app in the background within given limitations. Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for detailed information.

Why all these limitations you might ask yourself? It's to provide a good battery life to the user.

Edit:

For the periodic agent to start running the app must be started once. Further the agent must update a live tile (user must pin it to the start screen) or the app has to be once opened every 14 days.
Another option might be using [push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202977%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to trigger an update..

Comment: it is basically a tracker based application that will work between master and child phone. so that master can track child phone.application will install on child mobile without any UI

Comment: That can be done with a background agent, though you can only run once every 30 minutes.

Comment: thanks......Is it possible after installing the app from market place then app works only in background.